# ¿Generar relaciones en pgAdmin 4 (Postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Estoy dando mantenimiento a una base de datos en `Postgresql`, siendo sincero es muy compleja y no logro entenderla por completo. 
He buscado información para poder generar  relaciones entre las tablas, y así comprender de mejor forma la base de datos. Lo que he conseguido es que una consulta me genere un **"Explain"**, el cual al ejecutar mi consulta me aparece un cuadro de mensaje donde aparece la información de la tabla, pero no termina de ayudarme. **¿Existe alguna forma de realizar relaciones de mejor manera?**

Comment: Cuando dices *generar relaciones*, en realidad quieres decir *visualizar las relaciones*, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si quieres aprender **de verdad**, te recomiendo que aprendas a crear las relaciones por código, con los `CREATE TABLE...`. Crear tus relaciones en la pantallita, uniendo flechitas, es fácil, pero de ese modo no vas a aprender del todo el sentido profundo de las relaciones ni su funcionamiento... como por ejemplo las restricciones de integridad referencial y demás aspectos que la pantallita te impide ver.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo a donde vas con tu comentario, el problema es que necesito un punto de partida para comprender de manera general la base de datos. No se si relaciones por código, como indicas, pueda realizarlo. Ya que necesito saber la herencia de cada tabla. En sí, sería de mucha ayuda ver el panorama general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El GUI de [Navicat](https://www2.navicat.com/es/download/navicat-for-postgresql) es una excelente opción porque a medida que agregas tablas en el constructor de query gráfico hace las relaciones automáticamente (siempre y cuando existan las llaves foráneas):

[image: Navicat]

La otra opción eshacer un DUMP de tu base de datos, pero únicamente tomando el esquema:

```
pg_dump -U pgadmin my_base --schema-only
```

Ya en el resultado del DUMP puedes revisar todas las llaves foráneas y referencias a las tablas y campos de tu base.